# I am not able to display values with the help of sling models in AEM

Tags: java, aem

This is my model:

```
package org.aem.ubusina.core.models;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.apache.sling.models.annotations.Model;

@Model(adaptables = Resource.class)
public class PromoModel {


    @Inject
    public String image;

    @Inject
    public String text;

    @Inject
    public String desc;


    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return desc;
    }   

}
```

This is the HTML code:

This is Description: ${model.description}

This is title: ${model.title}

I have also included my model in the HTML using 
< data-sly-use.model="org.aem.ubusina.core.models.PromoModel">

However, I am not able to fetch values. Please help.

Comment: Can you please add more information about the resource you want to adapt. For example: You say that you want to display the resources title with `${model.title}`. But your model does not have a method `getTitle()`. So I assume you want to display the value of the resource property `jcr:title`. In this case you would have to either update your model class or as a shortcut use this in your HTL (Sightly) template: `${properties.jcr:title}`. It is also important to know which AEM version you are running.

Answer (score 0):

**org.apache.sling.models.api**

is the dependency you need to resolve before using sling models

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right you are not able to adapt to. Make sure you've the name = the string names within the model class. For example in your dialog.xml

```
<image name="./testImage" xtype="pathfield" .... />
```

Your model private would have

```
@Inject
@Optional //If the field is not required
private String testImage
public getTestImage(){
return this.testImage;
}
```

Comment: If the getter method is `private` you should not be able to use it in a HTL (Sightly) template.

Comment: Absolutely. Corrected my comment